# Pass unknown size array of structs to functions and fill

Tags: c, arrays, struct

First of, I'll admit I don't know much about C and pointers, but I've been reading up and have yet to find a solution. I have also tried some solutions found here on SO but none have worked.

The info to fill the structs, as well as the size of the array, is read from a file. So, I want to declare the array in main(), to use in further processing and pass it by reference to read_p5_info() where it is initialized and filled. 'configs' is to be filled by the configurations() function.

```
typedef struct pentomino_info pentomino_info; 

struct pentomino_info {
    char name;
    int orientations;
    int blocks[5][2];
    int configs[8];
};

int read_p5_info(int *npieces, int *matrix_size, pentomino_info **pieces) {
    // piece info is read from file
    // npiece and matrix_size are also read from the file
    // With file I'm testing with, npieces = 12 and matrix_size = 5

    *pieces = malloc(*npieces * sizeof *pieces);

    for (p = 0 ; p < *npieces ; p++) {
        pieces[p] = malloc(sizeof *pieces[p]);

        ret = fscanf(fp, "%c %*d %d %d %*d %*d %*f", &pieces[p]->name, &p5_rotations, &p5_flips);

        pieces[p]->orientations = p5_rotations * p5_flips;

        // read p5 blocks
        int b = 0;
        for (l = *matrix_size - 1 ; l >= 0 ; l--) {
            for (c = 0 ; c < *matrix_size ; c++) {
                // p5_char is a char read from the file
                if(p5_char == '#' || p5_char == 'X') {
                    pieces[p]->blocks[b][0]=c;
                    pieces[p]->blocks[b][1]=l;
                    b++;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

int main() {
    int npieces, matrix_size;
    pentomino_info *pieces; // array of p5 pieces

    int ret;

    ret = read_p5_info(&npieces, &matrix_size, &pieces);

    // configurations() operates on each piece individually
    configurations(matrix_size, &pieces[k]);
}
```

The pieces I'm talking about are [Pentominos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentomino). *npieces* is the number of pentaminos the file has information for, *matrix_size* is because *pentamino_info.blocks* has coordinates X,Y of the placement of each block in a *matrix_size* x *matrix_size* matrix.

I get segfault **at the end of main()**. *pieces[0]* seems fine but still gives me segfault, and the others are just malformed.

I tried to make the code a bit more compact by removing some parts that didn't seemed relevant, if I overdid it let me know. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: If you want a 2D matrix, you'll need to return a `pentomino_info **` or pass a `pentomino_info ***`.  Your pointer in the `main()` is for a 1D vector, not a 2D matrix.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I want a 1D vector. Basically pentamino_info pieces[npieces] , but I can't do that because npieces is only known after the file is read within read_p5_info()

Comment: OK; then why is your function busy allocating twice?  You just need to allocate the array once and then fill the members you've allocated.

Comment: Are you saying I don't need to allocate pieces[p] ? I've tried that and then I can't write in its members. I need to allocate space for the vector and for the structs in its indices, right?

Comment: As shown, you're using uninitialized variables `npieces` and `matrix_size` from your `main()` as if they are initialized inside the `read_p5_info()` function.  That makes it hard to know whether the problem is in your creation of an MCVE ([MCVE]) or that's really a factor in your troubles.  What is the difference between the matrix size and the number of pieces, and why is the term matrix being used if there's only an array or vector of pieces?  I'm confused; maybe you are too.  But if you want a simple vector of pieces, you only need one size and one allocation — unless you're a masochist.

Comment: At minimum, in the block ```int b = 0;
        for (l = *matrix_size - 1 ; l >= 0 ; l--) {
            for (c = 0 ; c < *matrix_size ; c++) {
                pieces[p]->blocks[b][0]=c;
                pieces[p]->blocks[b][1]=l;
                b++;
            }
        }```, with matrix size of 5, you are stepping way, way out of bounds as `b` increments.  This will cause trouble — a crash is entirely plausible — as you are writing to memory beyond what was allocated to you.

Comment: Yeah, that was actually my mistake in pasting the code here, I removed the if-statement that prevents b from going out of bounds. I've edited the question and also added what npieces and matrix_size are. But, if I may, a bit more straight to the point: Is the passing by reference well done? Is the memory allocation well done? Because I've tested the file reading part of the code in main() and it works, so I'd say that the problem is more the allocation and the array "getting back to main". The segfault only occurs at the end of main(), not before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`*pieces = malloc(*npieces * sizeof *pieces);` allocates the wrong amount of memory. Should be `sizeof **pieces`. The pattern is `P = malloc(N * sizeof *P);` as a cognitive cross-check, check that there is one more star on the front of the argument to sizeof.

`pieces[p]->x` should be `(*pieces)[p].x`, you make this error in multiple places.  In array notation, you wrote `pieces[p][0].x` but the correct indexing is `pieces[0][p].x`. The pointer `pieces` only points to one pointer, which then points to the first element of an array of infos.

If this is confusing I would recommend using "normal" pointers in your function, and then implementing the return-by-reference at the end, e.g.:

```
int n_pie = 12;  // or whatever you read

pentomino_info *pie = malloc(n_pie * sizeof *pie);
// ...
pie[p].orientations = bla;
// ...

*npieces = n_pie;
*pieces = pie;
return 0;
```

Comment: You are a lifesaver! Your "normal" pointers solution worked and I also understood your previous explanation. Thank you.